# Find nested embedded array with Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to filter out nested array elements inside a document, but nothing is showing.

Here is my schema:

```
//Product:
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    productname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'User must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function (str) {
          return validator.isAlphanumeric(str, 'en-US', { ignore: ' ' });
        },
        message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a valid username`,
      },
    },
    slug: String,
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A product must have a price'],
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    images: [String],
    variants: [Variant], //Schema
  },
  {
    id: false,
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);


//Variant:
const variantSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    // product: {
    //   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    //   ref: 'Product',
    // },
    // size: {
    //   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    //   ref: 'Size',
    // },
    // color: {
    //   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    //   ref: 'Color',
    // },
    size: {
      type: String,
      enum: {
        values: [
          '35',
          '35.5',
          '36',
          '36.5',
          '37',
          '37.5',
          '38',
          '38.5',
          '39',
          '39.5',
          '40',
          '41',
          '41.5',
          '42',
          '42.5',
          '43',
          '44',
          '44.5',
          '45',
          '46',
          '46.5',
          '47',
          '47.5',
          '48',
          'S',
          'M',
          'L',
          'XL',
          'XXL',
          'XS',
          'Onesize',
        ],
        message: 'Please enter correct sizing format !',
      },
      required: [true, 'Please enter sizing !'],
    },
    color: { type: String, required: [true, 'Please enter color !'] },
    quantity: Number,
  },
  {
    id: false,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);
```

**Note**: variants is embedded so is exported as Schema.

So I'm trying to filter out variant with color Grey like in the pic: [image]

What I did was finding the product by slug and filtering using the color property inside variant.

```
const document = await Model.find({
 slug: req.params.slug,
 variants: {
  color: 'Grey'
 }
});
```

It shows me nothing, 0

I also tried with `"variants.color" : "Grey"`
But this time it gives me all the result. So it seems filter didnt apply or simply not worked.

Comment: Could you clarify whether "results" in the phrase "it gives me all the result." refers to products or variants? The dot notation is correct, and it should return only products with at least 1 matching variant. Whole products. If you expect to retrieve only matching variants you need to use aggregation framework to filter the array of variants.

Comment: refers to variants.

Comment: @AlexBlex I want to return product with matching variants, but the find method returns the product with all the variants. How can I do it with only matching variant (with product as well)?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need virtuals in this case. According to [populate() documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) this could be achieved by "match" option.

The solution should be:

```
const document = await Model.find({
  slug: req.params.slug
}).populate("variants", {
  match: { color: "Grey" } // query for subdocument
});
```

Comment: variants seem to be subdocuments, not references ones. Therefore using 'populate' does not really make sense.

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to SO, and congrats with your first answer. I'm afraid Fabian is right. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html explicitly says population is for documents from other collections. There is nothing to deference when subdocuments are already embedded in the main document. I am sure OP will be grateful if you can provide some code how to use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html  to https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/ subdocuments tho.